# Could Stack Overflow include backend language compilers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We have seen that a lot of websites like [HackerEarth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HackerEarth), [HackerRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HackerRank) have compilers for all the languages (Java, C/C++, etc.). We can use these to compile and run our code on these websites only.

Stack Overflow is one of the most-used websites and there are programming questions. So would it be better if Stack Overflow included a compiler for languages like Java, C, C++, etc.? It would be easy and helpful for both the user who is asking a question and the user who is answering.

Comment: I'm going to take a stab at **never**... doing so is 1) a massive risk if done incorrectly and 2) massively resource intensive - some questions have highly complicated algorithms over large generated datasets or require lots of network activity and fetching resources from external sites... Those either wouldn't work thus making it useless or potentially open SO up for all sorts of attack avenues...

Comment: Also - what about compiler specific issues or library specific issues... How many combinations of that would have to be catered for... It just wouldn't be practical in the least.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't count on this ever happening.

The resources required to compile and run the code, with the sheer *amount* of questions SO gets makes this a massive resource hog.
That alone is reason enough not to bother.

Then there's

- Version-specific issues for each language.
- Memory / CPU load.
- Security risks
- Memory / CPU load.
- Development costs vs returns
- Did I mention Memory / CPU load?

Comment: Devil's advocate: then why bother for JavaScript?

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins because with JS the load is for the client.

Comment: Because JavaScript doesn't require server-side code compilation/execution. Server-side, the impact should be negligible. There are no back-end security risks, as long as the back-end doesn't run the code.

Comment: Version-specific issues alone make this a no-go for Stack Overflow. Most competition sites pick a few languages and only support very few versions of each one. On top of that, many force you to fit your code into a site-specific framework so it can be executed on their servers. This would be way too restrictive for SO.